# Calculate the parallel value of resistors at base of common emitter amplifier

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, analog, bjt, common-emitter

In an exam paper I saw a question to determine the parallel value of the R1 and R2 resistors in the image below but I am not sure how to do this. I tried using the bias equations for a common emitter amplifier but I have not been able to get the answer. I put the exact question in the image below so you can see how exactly it was asked. I am only asking for question (c) as I have done the first two (I may or may not be correct). You do not necessarily need to solve it but if you at least know formula or method I could use it would be very helpful.

[image: The Whole Question]

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is confusing because of the way "X" is indicated in the schematic.

What they likely want to ask about is the input resistance seen by the source \$V_{in}\$.

First, assume the frequency is high enough that capacitor C<sub>1</sub> can be ignored. Then, the input resistance of the circuit is essentially the resistance at "point X", if X were drawn pointing to the same node of the circuit, but somewhere to the left of where R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub> connect to it.

That means the the input resistance of the amplifier is given by 
$$R_1 || R_2 || R_{in}$$
where \$R_{in}\$ is the input resistance of the emitter-degenerate common-emitter amplifier.

So you just have to work out what \$R_{in}\$ is (you have enough information in your schematic), and then find what needs to be put in parallel with that to get 10 kOhms.